# Objective c++ supported by NDK or not

Tags: c++, objective-c, android-ndk

I want to ask whether Objective c ++ code works for android or not, or one need to convert it into C++ so that android NDK will support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the official Android NDK does not support Obj-c but there are some improved NDK ([http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk/7](http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk/7%29)) which support many extra languages.